# How to split dataset to two datasets with unique and duplicate rows each?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to take duplicate records in a Spark scala Dataframe. for example, I want to take duplicate values based on 3 columns like "id", "name", "age".condition part contains any no of columns(Dynamic Input). based on the column value I want to take the duplicate records.

the below code I have tried. only one attribute I tried. I don't know how to do if more than one column.

My Code:

```
 var s= "age|id|name " // Note- This is dynamic input. so it will increase or decrease
 var columnNames= s.replace('|', ',')


val findDuplicateRecordsDF= spark.sql("SELECT * FROM " + dbname + "." + tablename)
findDuplicateRecordsDF.show()
findDuplicateRecordsDF.withColumn("count", count("*")
      .over(Window.partitionBy($"id"))) // here how to add more than one column?(Dynamic input) 
      .where($"count">1)
      .show()
```

Input Dataframe: (findDuplicateRecordsDF.show())

```
       --------------------------------------------------------
       |  id   |  name | age |  phone      | email_id          |
       |-------------------------------------------------------|  
       |  3    | sam   | 23  |  9876543210 | sam@yahoo.com     | 
       |  7    | ram   | 27  |  8765432190 | ram@gmail.com     |
       |  3    | sam   | 28  |  9876543210 | sam@yahoo.com     | 
       |  6    | haris | 30  |  6543210777 | haris@gmail.com   |
       |  9    | ram   | 27  |  8765432130 | ram94@gmail.com   |
       |  6    | haris | 24  |  6543210777 | haris@gmail.com   | 
       |  4    | karthi| 26  |  4321066666 | karthi@gmail.com  | 
       --------------------------------------------------------
```

here I am going to take duplicate records based on 4 columns(id, name, phone, email). the above one is example data frame. original data frame contains any no of columns.

The Output Dataframe should be

1. Duplicate Records Output

   ```
          --------------------------------------------------------
          |  id   |  name | age |  phone      | email_id          |
          |-------------------------------------------------------|  
          |  3    | sam   | 23  |  9876543210 | sam@yahoo.com     | 
          |  3    | sam   | 28  |  9876543210 | sam@yahoo.com     | 
          |  6    | haris | 30  |  6543210777 | haris@gmail.com   |
          |  6    | haris | 24  |  6543210777 | haris@gmail.com   | 
           --------------------------------------------------------
   ```
2. Unique Records Dataframe Output:

   ```
         --------------------------------------------------------
        |  id   |  name | age |  phone      | email_id          |
        |-------------------------------------------------------|  
        |  7    | ram   | 27  |  8765432190 | ram@gmail.com     |
        |  9    | ram   | 27  |  8765432130 | ram94@gmail.com   |
        |  4    | karthi| 26  |  4321066666 | karthi@gmail.com  | 
         --------------------------------------------------------
   ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can specify comma separated list of columns in `partitionBy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions. Check this out

```
scala> val df = Seq((3,"sam",23,"9876543210","sam@yahoo.com"),(7,"ram",27,"8765432190","ram@gmail.com"),(3,"sam",28,"9876543210","sam@yahoo.com"),(6,"haris",30,"6543210777","haris@gmail.com"),(9,"ram",27,"8765432130","ram94@gmail.com"),(6,"haris",24,"6543210777","haris@gmail.com"),(4,"karthi",26,"4321066666","karthi@gmail.com")).toDF("id","name","age","phone","email_id")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> val dup_cols = List("id","name","phone","email_id");
dup_cols: List[String] = List(id, name, phone, email_id)

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("contact")

scala> val dup_cols_qry = dup_cols.mkString(" count(*) over(partition by ", "," , " ) as cnt ")
dup_cols_qry: String = " count(*) over(partition by id,name,phone,email_id ) as cnt "

scala> val df2 = spark.sql("select *,"+ dup_cols_qry + " from contact ")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string ... 4 more fields]

scala> df2.show(false)
+---+------+---+----------+----------------+---+
|id |name  |age|phone     |email_id        |cnt|
+---+------+---+----------+----------------+---+
|4  |karthi|26 |4321066666|karthi@gmail.com|1  |
|7  |ram   |27 |8765432190|ram@gmail.com   |1  |
|9  |ram   |27 |8765432130|ram94@gmail.com |1  |
|3  |sam   |23 |9876543210|sam@yahoo.com   |2  |
|3  |sam   |28 |9876543210|sam@yahoo.com   |2  |
|6  |haris |30 |6543210777|haris@gmail.com |2  |
|6  |haris |24 |6543210777|haris@gmail.com |2  |
+---+------+---+----------+----------------+---+


scala> df2.createOrReplaceTempView("contact2")
```

//Duplicates

```
scala>  spark.sql("select " + dup_cols.mkString(",") + " from contact2 where cnt = 2").show
+---+-----+----------+---------------+
| id| name|     phone|       email_id|
+---+-----+----------+---------------+
|  3|  sam|9876543210|  sam@yahoo.com|
|  3|  sam|9876543210|  sam@yahoo.com|
|  6|haris|6543210777|haris@gmail.com|
|  6|haris|6543210777|haris@gmail.com|
+---+-----+----------+---------------+
```

// Unique

```
scala>  spark.sql("select " + dup_cols.mkString(",") + " from contact2 where cnt = 1").show
+---+------+----------+----------------+
| id|  name|     phone|        email_id|
+---+------+----------+----------------+
|  4|karthi|4321066666|karthi@gmail.com|
|  7|   ram|8765432190|   ram@gmail.com|
|  9|   ram|8765432130| ram94@gmail.com|
+---+------+----------+----------------+
```

**EDIT2:**

```
val df = Seq(
  (4,"karthi",26,"4321066666","karthi@gmail.com"),
  (6,"haris",24,"6543210777","haris@gmail.com"),
  (7,"ram",27,"8765432190","ram@gmail.com"),
  (9,"ram",27,"8765432190","ram@gmail.com"),
  (6,"haris",24,"6543210777","haris@gmail.com"),
  (3,"sam",23,"9876543210","sam@yahoo.com"),
  (3,"sam",23,"9876543210","sam@yahoo.com"),
  (3,"sam",28,"9876543210","sam@yahoo.com"),
  (6,"haris",30,"6543210777","haris@gmail.com")
  ).toDF("id","name","age","phone","email_id")

val dup_cols = List("name","phone","email_id")
val dup_cols_str = dup_cols.mkString(",")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("contact")
val dup_cols_count_qry = " count(*) over(partition by " + dup_cols_str + " ) as cnt "
val dup_cols_row_num_qry = " row_number() over(partition by " + dup_cols_str + " order by " + dup_cols_str + " ) as rwn "
val df2 = spark.sql("select *,"+ dup_cols_count_qry + "," + dup_cols_row_num_qry + " from contact ")
df2.show(false)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("contact2")
spark.sql("select id, " + dup_cols_str + " from contact2 where cnt > 1 and rwn > 1").show
```

Results:

```
+---+-----+----------+---------------+
| id| name|     phone|       email_id|
+---+-----+----------+---------------+
|  6|haris|6543210777|haris@gmail.com|
|  6|haris|6543210777|haris@gmail.com|
|  3|  sam|9876543210|  sam@yahoo.com|
|  3|  sam|9876543210|  sam@yahoo.com|
|  9|  ram|8765432190|  ram@gmail.com|
+---+-----+----------+---------------+
```

**EDIT3:**  - Null condition check

```
val df = Seq(
  (4,"karthi",26,"4321066666","karthi@gmail.com"),
  (6,"haris",30,"6543210777","haris@gmail.com"),
  (6,"haris",30,null,"haris@gmail.com"),
  (7,"ram",27,"8765432190","ram@gmail.com"),
  (9,"ram",27,"8765432190","ram@gmail.com"),
  (6,"haris",24,"6543210777","haris@gmail.com"),
  (6,null,24,"6543210777",null),
  (3,"sam",23,"9876543210","sam@yahoo.com"),
  (3,"sam",23,"9876543210","sam@yahoo.com"),
  (3,"sam",28,"9876543210","sam@yahoo.com"),
  (6,"haris",24,"6543210777","haris@gmail.com")
).toDF("id","name","age","phone","email_id")

val all_cols = df.columns
val dup_cols = List("name","phone","email_id")
val rem_cols = all_cols.diff(dup_cols)
val dup_cols_str = dup_cols.mkString(",")
val rem_cols_str = rem_cols.mkString(",")
val dup_cols_length = dup_cols.length
val df_null_col = dup_cols.map( x => when(col(x).isNull,0).otherwise(1)).reduce( _ + _ )
val df_null = df.withColumn("null_count", df_null_col)
df_null.createOrReplaceTempView("contact")
df_null.show(false)

val dup_cols_count_qry = " count(*) over(partition by " + dup_cols_str + " ) as cnt "
val dup_cols_row_num_qry = " row_number() over(partition by " + dup_cols_str + " order by " + dup_cols_str + " ) as rwn "
val df2 = spark.sql("select *,"+ dup_cols_count_qry + "," + dup_cols_row_num_qry + " from contact " + " where null_count  = " + dup_cols_length )
df2.show(false)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("contact2")
val df3 = spark.sql("select " +  dup_cols_str +  ", " + rem_cols_str + " from contact2 where cnt > 1 and rwn > 1")
df3.show(false)
```

Results:

```
+---+------+---+----------+----------------+----------+
|id |name  |age|phone     |email_id        |null_count|
+---+------+---+----------+----------------+----------+
|4  |karthi|26 |4321066666|karthi@gmail.com|3         |
|6  |haris |30 |6543210777|haris@gmail.com |3         |
|6  |haris |30 |null      |haris@gmail.com |2         |
|7  |ram   |27 |8765432190|ram@gmail.com   |3         |
|9  |ram   |27 |8765432190|ram@gmail.com   |3         |
|6  |haris |24 |6543210777|haris@gmail.com |3         |
|6  |null  |24 |6543210777|null            |1         |
|3  |sam   |23 |9876543210|sam@yahoo.com   |3         |
|3  |sam   |23 |9876543210|sam@yahoo.com   |3         |
|3  |sam   |28 |9876543210|sam@yahoo.com   |3         |
|6  |haris |24 |6543210777|haris@gmail.com |3         |
+---+------+---+----------+----------------+----------+


|id |name  |age|phone     |email_id        |null_count|cnt|rwn|
+---+------+---+----------+----------------+----------+---+---+
|6  |haris |30 |6543210777|haris@gmail.com |3         |3  |1  |
|6  |haris |24 |6543210777|haris@gmail.com |3         |3  |2  |
|6  |haris |24 |6543210777|haris@gmail.com |3         |3  |3  |
|3  |sam   |23 |9876543210|sam@yahoo.com   |3         |3  |1  |
|3  |sam   |23 |9876543210|sam@yahoo.com   |3         |3  |2  |
|3  |sam   |28 |9876543210|sam@yahoo.com   |3         |3  |3  |
|7  |ram   |27 |8765432190|ram@gmail.com   |3         |2  |1  |
|9  |ram   |27 |8765432190|ram@gmail.com   |3         |2  |2  |
|4  |karthi|26 |4321066666|karthi@gmail.com|3         |1  |1  |
+---+------+---+----------+----------------+----------+---+---+

+-----+----------+---------------+---+---+
|name |phone     |email_id       |id |age|
+-----+----------+---------------+---+---+
|haris|6543210777|haris@gmail.com|6  |24 |
|haris|6543210777|haris@gmail.com|6  |24 |
|sam  |9876543210|sam@yahoo.com  |3  |23 |
|sam  |9876543210|sam@yahoo.com  |3  |28 |
|ram  |8765432190|ram@gmail.com  |9  |27 |
+-----+----------+---------------+---+---+
```

**blank check**

```
val df_null_col = dup_cols.map( x => when(col(x).isNull or regexp_replace(col(x), """^\s*$""","")=== lit(""),0).otherwise(1)).reduce( _ + _ )
```

Filter only when all 3 columns are either blank or null

```
val df = Seq(
  (4,"karthi",26,"4321066666","karthi@gmail.com"),
  (6,"haris",30,"6543210777","haris@gmail.com"),
  (6,null,30,null,null),
  (7,"ram",27,"8765432190","ram@gmail.com"),
  (9,"",27,"",""),
  (7,"ram",27,"8765432190","ram@gmail.com"),
  (6,"haris",24,"6543210777","haris@gmail.com"),
  (6,null,24,"6543210777",null),
  (3,"sam",23,"9876543210","sam@yahoo.com"),
  (3,null,23,"9876543210","sam@yahoo.com"),
  (3,null,28,"9876543213",null),
  (6,"haris",24,null,"haris@gmail.com")
).toDF("id","name","age","phone","email_id")

val all_cols = df.columns
val dup_cols = List("name","phone","email_id")
val rem_cols = all_cols.diff(dup_cols)
val dup_cols_str = dup_cols.mkString(",")
val rem_cols_str = rem_cols.mkString(",")
val dup_cols_length = dup_cols.length
//val df_null_col = dup_cols.map( x => when(col(x).isNull,0).otherwise(1)).reduce( _ + _ )
val df_null_col = dup_cols.map( x => when(col(x).isNull or regexp_replace(col(x),lit("""^\s*$"""),lit("")) === lit(""),0).otherwise(1)).reduce( _ + _ )
val df_null = df.withColumn("null_count", df_null_col)
df_null.createOrReplaceTempView("contact")
df_null.show(false)

val dup_cols_count_qry = " count(*) over(partition by " + dup_cols_str + " ) as cnt "
val dup_cols_row_num_qry = " row_number() over(partition by " + dup_cols_str + " order by " + dup_cols_str + " ) as rwn "
//val df2 = spark.sql("select *,"+ dup_cols_count_qry + "," + dup_cols_row_num_qry + " from contact " + " where null_count  = " + dup_cols_length )
val df2 = spark.sql("select *,"+ dup_cols_count_qry + "," + dup_cols_row_num_qry + " from contact " + " where null_count  !=  0 ")
df2.show(false)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("contact2")
val df3 = spark.sql("select " +  dup_cols_str +  ", " + rem_cols_str + " from contact2 where cnt > 1 and rwn > 1")
df3.show(false)
```

Comment: I am getting below exception at the time of spark-submit                                  
 == SQL ==
select *, count(*) over(partition by [condition: string] ) as cnt  from contact
-------------------------------------^^^

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:114)

Comment: seems dup_cols_qry is empty string.. check again

Comment: yes, now it's working... Thank you  stack0114106... No that is not a duplicate question...another question explanation is "I am taking each column or required column to count number of unique and duplicate records.for more information read that question"

Comment: I got the question.. I'm just giving a try.. almost half done.. btw are you from QA team.. your questions are always concerned with meta-programming

Comment: I have the answer for that question.. I guess SO may not allow you to ask questions for sometime..ask a new question or give your mail-id

Comment: here one small change in my requirement--- suppose I am having 3 duplicates rows with the same value, here I want to take 1 row of value and put it into unique results. remaining 2 rows of value in duplicate records.

Comment: in that case create one more table on top of the result by adding row_number after partitioning by the required columns.. then select row number=1

Comment: can you give your mail id to resolve one problem in above requirment

Comment: hi.. just sent from my mail

Answer (score 0):

You need to give comma separated col names.

```
col1 ..col2 should be of string type.
     val window= Window.partitionBy(col1,col2,..)


    findDuplicateRecordsDF.withColumn("count", count("*")
          .over(window)
          .where($"count">1)
          .show()
```

Comment: the input contain N no of columns .. Its dynamic value